# Error in int vba function calculation?

Tags: vba

I am doing a calculation of values using Microsoft Excel vba.

I have a portion of codes like the below:

`INT(151.2 * 100)`
I notice that the result from this calculation is 15119 but the correct result should be 15220.

It is ok if i remove the `INT()`
`151.2 * 100`
The result returned will be 15220.

Can anyone advise why is there such a difference and whether it is correct to simply remove the `INT()` to achieve the correct result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic.

```
a = (151.2 * 100)
Print Int(a)
15119
Print a
15120
Print a = 15120
False
```

There is no double-precision number to represent the result of `151.2 * 100` exactly as 15120. The closest one is apparently just under 15120. When you `Int` it, it gets truncated, i.e. rounded down to 15119.

Instead of truncating, you could round:

```
Print CInt(a)
15120
Print Round(a)
15120
```

Note that if you have a variable `i` of type Integer and you just say `i = 151.2 * 100` as you suggest, then you are *implicitly* coercing the result to an integer i.e. implicitly saying `i = CInt(151.2 * 100)`. I think it's better practice to be explicit.

Comment: As an aside, if 151.2 was stored in a variable declared as currency or a variant subtyped as decimal, there would not be a problem.